# Flash NOR: 1-1-2 mode vs 1-2-2 mode

Tags: embedded, driver, spi, firmware, flash-memory

I am working on a Quad-SPI driver that communicated with a Flash NOR device. I am trying to understand the differences between various modes like 1-1-2, 1-2-2, 4-4-4 etc. The x-y-z stand for the number of lines used for command-address-data.

In my understanding if we are IO limited, we may want to use only two Input/Output (SIO[0-1]) lines. And hence a 1-1-2 or 1-2-2 configuration should be used. Now, my why would someone choose 1-1-2 over 1-2-2? If we already have 2 lines available, 1-2-2 would make most sense (IMHO). Is my understanding correct here?

Answer (score 1):

From a software point of view, you just implement the best mode that the device on the board supports.  There may be hardware or supply chain reasons to buy a part that doesn't support the fastest mode.

Note that the address is only a tiny part of what is transmitted, so if a device supports both 1-1-2 and 1-2-2 and you already have a driver for 1-1-2 then it might not be worth your while to implement 1-2-2.

A bigger consideration is read and write data commands.  Consider that some devices might support a 2 bit data phase for read but only 1 bit for write.

Answer (score 0):

The command always has to be sent on the number of lines the device expects it. That's almost always 1 bit for flash devices. There are some SPI RAM chips that expect even the command on 4 (or 8!) lines. These devices cannot be used with standard SPI, they only work with QSPI (or octal SPI). As far as I know this is not configurable. You cannot opt for 4-4-4 if your device is hard-wired to receive the command on 1 line, or the other way around.

The command tells the chip how will the address and data be sent and whether it's 3 or 4 bytes, whether there are any dummy cycles etc... You can select what you want, taking into consideration what the flash device and your QSPI controller support.

Quickly looked through some SPI flash datasheets that I worked with recently, and I did not see any that are limited to e.g. 1-1-4 and can't do 1-4-4. It seems that when a device supports quad output, it supports both the EBh and 6Bh commands.

However, your QSPI controller, especially in memory-mapped mode, might be limited. I have such a controller on my desk right now: the Sitara Am2634 from Texas Instruments. When using memory-mapped mode it always sends the command and address on 1 line, only the data phase is using all 4 lines. Thus command EBh cannot be used with this chip, only 6Bh, provided that the selected flash device also supports that. When controlling the communication manually, not in the memory mapped mode, this limitation does not apply. Apart from DDR mode everything else is possible.